# git Fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed on branch push

Tags: memory, git, github

I know this has been asked a lot but I did not manage to get any solution to solve my problem.

My coworker assigned me on a new project. The application is hosted on test Debian server with git installed.

First I have created my branch :

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

Then I have done small modifications to some files.

When I tried to push it to Github (using my github account)

```
git add myfile.php
git commit -m "my first commit"
git push origin mybranch
```

I get this error :

> fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed

I don't understand what this mean. The total size of the files I tried to push is 156Ko. Moreover the total size of the project is only 10,9Mo.

I tried to reboot the server but the same happen.

When I run `free` on the server I get :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        505312     239532     265780          0      51576      71580
-/+ buffers/cache:     116376     388936
Swap:            0          0          0
```

My coworkers never had this problem before, even on the same test server.

Can someone highlight me on the reason of this error and a possible workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings in `.git/config` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903/git-on-windows-out-of-memory-malloc-failed)?

Comment: Yes but no luck...

Comment: Can you try again with the `-v` flag, `git push -v`, and post the full error (redacting your repo info of course).

Comment: The `-v` flag does not add anything to the error message...

Comment: This looks like a bug somewhere. What version of Debian does the machine have? Can you reproduce the problem by cloning a local repository rather than one on github? If you can reproduce the problem without using any credentials or private information, run `strace -o git.strace -tt git push origin mybranch` (or whatever the failing `git …` command is) and post the resulting `git.strace` file (don't post the trace if it might contain something like a password).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn out it was indeed a ram problem. 268mo was not enough for git to function properly.

I solved the problem by adding 1Go of swap to the server:

```bsh
$ sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
$ sudo mkswap /swapfile
$ sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Comment: How did you do that, Im getting same issue.

Comment: for example take a look at it: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: This turned out to be my issue as well. Running on a small AWS EC2

Comment: Great answer, I let myself top it up with increasing internal GIT limits following creation of the swap file:    

    git config pack.packSizeLimit 1g  
git config pack.deltaCacheSize 1g
git config pack.windowMemory 1g
git config core.packedGitLimit 1g
git config core.packedGitWindowSize 1g

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error as I was running jenkins in docker

I stop container and run git and this fixed the problem

Try to free some more space in RAM

Answer (score 0):

I checked my RAM usage.

Enter command:

```
free -mh
```

I got very little left of RAM.

So I stopped my docker container and checked my RAM again.

Now it's back to normal.